# Prove that a bounded decreasing sequence $\big\{ {x_n} \big\}$ converges

Tags: analysis

Prove that a bounded decreasing sequence $\big\{ {x_n} \big\}$ converges

I proved this using Bolzano-weierstrass thm but I was wondering how else I could prove it without using that thm.

Comment: The existence of the greatest lower bound (for a decreasing  sequence) or the least upper bound (for an increasing sequence) is enough.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this: for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_i \geq L$ and since $(x_n)$ is decreasing $x_{n+1} \leq x_n$ and $\inf{x_n} = L$ (if L is the greatest lower bound). We then necessarily have that as $n \to \infty, x_n \to L$.